# Remote mouse movement is jerky

Tags: java, sockets, mouseevent, awtrobot

I'm using a mouselistener and the robot class to move a mouse on one computer and have it move the cursor on another computer It's a precursor to a remote desktop project I am working on. One problem I have already stumbled upon is jerky mouse movement. I've gone over my code a hundred times and I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Here are the 3 server files that send the mouse movements to the client.

TC_ServerListener.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TC_ServerListener {
    private JFrame mainTCframe = new JFrame();
    private JDesktopPane mainDesktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new TC_ServerListener().startServer();
    }

    public void startServer() {

        try {
            setupGUI();

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients.");
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                new TC_ServerStarter(clientSocket, mainDesktopPane);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TC_ServerListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void setupGUI(){
            mainTCframe.add(mainDesktopPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainTCframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainTCframe.setExtendedState(mainTCframe.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            mainTCframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

TC_ServerStarter.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TC_ServerStarter extends Thread {

    int counter = 0;

    JPanel listenerPanel = new JPanel();
    JInternalFrame listenerFrame = new JInternalFrame("TestClient", true, true, true);
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle();

    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnv;
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDev;
    Dimension dim;
    Dimension clientDim;
    Dimension serverDim;

    static DataOutputStream kbOut;
    static DataOutputStream mouseMoveOut;
    static DataOutputStream mouseClickOut;
    static DataOutputStream mouseDragOut;

    Socket clientSocket;
    JDesktopPane mainDesktopPane;

    PrintWriter writer;
    Scanner dataScanner;

    public TC_ServerStarter(Socket cs, JDesktopPane mdp) {
        clientSocket = cs;
        mainDesktopPane = mdp;

        start();
    }

    public void setupGUI() {
        listenerFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        listenerFrame.getContentPane().add(listenerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        listenerFrame.setSize(100,100);
        mainDesktopPane.add(listenerFrame);

        try {
            listenerFrame.setMaximum(true);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TC_ServerStarter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        listenerPanel.setFocusable(true);
        listenerFrame.setVisible(true);
    }



        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                setupGUI();

                String clientIP = clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                System.out.println("Client connected from " + clientIP);

                writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                dataScanner = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                int screenHeight = dataScanner.nextInt();
                int screenWidth = dataScanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Setting screen size: " + screenHeight + "x" + screenWidth);
                clientDim = new Dimension(screenHeight, screenWidth);

                new KvmSender(clientSocket, listenerPanel, clientDim);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TC_ServerStarter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
              }
            }
        }
```

KvmSender.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class KvmSender implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private JPanel listenerPanel;
    private Dimension clientDim;
    private PrintWriter clientWriter;

    public KvmSender(Socket cs, JPanel lp, Dimension cd) {
        clientSocket = cs;
        listenerPanel = lp;
        clientDim = cd;

        listenerPanel.addKeyListener(this);
        listenerPanel.addMouseListener(this);
        listenerPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        try {
            clientWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Ready to send commands.");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        try {
            double scaleX = clientDim.getWidth() / listenerPanel.getWidth();
            double scaleY = clientDim.getHeight() / listenerPanel.getHeight();
            int mouseX = (int)(me.getX() * scaleX);
            int mouseY = (int)(me.getY() * scaleY);

            clientWriter.println(1);
            clientWriter.println(mouseX);
            clientWriter.println(mouseY);
            System.out.println("Sending mouse: " + mouseX + "," + mouseY);
            clientWriter.flush();

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing mouse data to server");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

}
```

And then the 2 client files.

TC_ClientStarter.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TC_ClientStarter extends Thread {

    private final static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.50";

    JPanel clientPanel = new JPanel();
    JFrame clientFrame = new JFrame();

    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnv;
    Rectangle screenRect;
    Dimension screenSize;

    static PrintWriter dataWriter;

    Robot tcRobot;

    Socket clientSocket;

    public void setupGUI() {

        clientFrame.add(clientPanel);
        clientFrame.setSize(200,200);
        clientFrame.setVisible(true);
        clientFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        clientPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TC_ClientStarter().setupClient();
    }

    public void setupClient() {

        try {
            screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            screenRect = new Rectangle(screenSize.height, screenSize.width);

            clientSocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, 1111);
            System.out.println("Connected to Commander.");

            System.out.println("Sending screen size: " + screenRect.height + "x" + screenRect.width);
            dataWriter = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            dataWriter.println(screenRect.height);
            dataWriter.println(screenRect.width);
            dataWriter.flush();

            tcRobot = new Robot();

            setupGUI();

            new TC_ClientReceiver(clientSocket, tcRobot);


            } catch (ConnectException ece) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to server: " + SERVER_IP);
        } catch (IOException | AWTException eio) {
            Logger.getLogger(TC_ClientStarter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, eio);
        }
    }
}
```

TC_ClientReceiver.java

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class TC_ClientReceiver extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Robot tcRobot;

    private Scanner clientScanner;

    private int mouseX, mouseY;

    public TC_ClientReceiver(Socket cs, Robot tcr) {
        clientSocket = cs;
        tcRobot = tcr;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        try {
            clientScanner = new Scanner(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Waiting for commands.");
            while (true) {

                int commandID = clientScanner.nextInt();
                //System.out.println("CommandID: " + commandID);
                switch (commandID) {

                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Mouse move");
                        mouseX = clientScanner.nextInt();
                        mouseY = clientScanner.nextInt();
                        tcRobot.mouseMove(mouseX, mouseY);
                        System.out.println(mouseX + "," + mouseY);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TC_ClientReceiver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I should add that I found someone who's written a remove server/client remote desktop app in java and when I run it, the mouse movement is smooth, unlike my own code.

Comment: the network latency is probably is the root cause of the jerky motion. i can think of two theoretical solutions (just guessing here): 1. implement a slight buffering algorithm so that movements are tracked accuracy over time. the buffer is longer than the slowest network latency. ie. how digital media does it. 2. implement a smoothing algorithm which "fills in the blanks" and traces a smooth line between updated points

Comment: having said that, solution 2 is probably better. i don't think the mouse events you get in java are always very smooth themselves. not enough to have it look natural.

Comment: The frustrating thing is that I've modelled my program after another and the other one is not jerky at all. For capturing the mouse and then moving the mouse, we use basically the same functions without any buffering or mouse smoothing. I have a mouse smoothing algorithm that I will try anyway but it shouldnt need it.

Comment: The mouse smoothing seems to be the solution. Thanks!